# Как найти индекс символа в строке?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет!
Мне нужно найти индекс символа в строке. Есть функция `indexOf`, которая идеально подходит, но она не работает в `ie7`.

Какие есть еще варианты? (на `jquery` тоже пойдет)

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

В цикле пройтись:

```
function indexOf(str, target){
    for(var i= 0, l = str.length; i<l; i++){
        if(str[i] === target){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; 
}
```

Использовать [jQuery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
$.inArray(target, str);
```

Использовать Underscore [_.indexOf](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf)

```
_.indexOf(str.split(''), target)
```